# Разделить массив с датами на дни, месяцы и годы

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу курсовой (что-то вроде программы для управляющего отелем), и мне нужна кое-какая помощь.
У меня есть таблица `Reservations`, в которой хранится информация о забронированных номерах. В ней помимо остальных полей есть поля `start_date` (дата поселения) и `end_date` (дата выселения). Мне нужно, чтобы когда `end_date` становилась больше текущей даты, данный номер освобождался. Для этого я разделил день, месяц и год текущей даты:

```
string[] datenow =
        label11.Text.Split(new char[]{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

и буду сравнивать их с днем, месяцем и годом *end_date* (ничего лучше я не придумал).

Я записал все значения столбца `end_date` в массив `dates`, но теперь не совсем понимаю, как мне разделить каждую дату для того, чтобы можно было сравнивать с текущей. Надеюсь, что не слишком плохо объяснил, может кто-нибудь подсказать, как это реализовать? Ниже код:

```
DataTable Reservations = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection coon = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = coon;
    cmd.CommandText = "select end_date from Reservations";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(Reservations);
}
const int size = 500;
string[] dates = new string[size];
for (int i = 0; i < Reservations.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dates[i] = Convert.ToString(Reservations.Rows[i]["end_date"]);
}
```

Comment: почему бы не что то типа `select * from reservations r where r.enddate < текущая дата and status != closed` ?

Comment: Я изначально так и хотел сделать.. Но из-за одной проблемы пришлось присваивать полям с датами тип nvarchar, а не date. В общем, когда я записывал дату в базу данных, вместе с ней в datagridview записывалось и время и появлялась ошибка (уже не помню какая), в инете долго искал, не нашёл как исправить её или задать формат даты без времени. Пришлось использовать вот такой кривой способ.

Comment: если вам не надо время - пишите в БД дату без времени, какие с этим проблемы? Или если не знаете как это делать, пишите дату, а время ставьте полночь.

Comment: @tym32167 я ввожу только дату, и почему-то выдает ошибку "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints", и в datagridview отображается время (полночь) с датой, а если открыть таблицу, то там дата без времени. Не знаете, в чем может быть проблема? Вроде бы null'ов нигде нет, ошибка возникает только после ввода даты.

Comment: Чтобы помочь вам с хранилищем - нужно чтобы вы выложили схему БД. По поводу исходного вопроса, моё предложение:

    `var expired = end_dates.Where(stringDate => DateTime.Parse(stringDate) > DateTime.Now);
    foreach (var end_date in expired)
    {
        // To do
    }`

Comment: Опять же, получив структуру DateTime можно обратиться к свойствам и методам уже с днями, месяцами, миллисекундами и всем остальным... Но лучше максимально далеко уйти от прямого сравнения этих вещей, идеально - оставить эту работу за СУБД.